# How to add if else inside the Tabs in react bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I try to execute following code but I got some error.
Error : ReactBootstrap: The `Tab` component is not meant to be rendered! It's an abstract component that is only valid as a direct Child of the `Tabs` Component. For custom tabs components use TabPane and TabsContainer directly.

```
import { Row, Col, Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
import One from "../One.jsx";
//One,Two .. etc There are more

render(
  <Tabs>
        <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1"><One/></Tab>                           
        <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2"><Two/></Tab>                           
        <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3"><Three/></Tab>   
  {this.state.type === type && (
        <Tab eventKey={4} title="Tab 4"><Four/></Tab>                           
        <Tab eventKey={5} title="Tab 5"><Five/></Tab>                           
        <Tab eventKey={6} title="Tab 6"><Six/></Tab>  
 )}
  </Tabs>
)
```

Comment: can I see your import statements?

Comment: Edited with imports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can construct new `Tab` components like that using conditional rendering. As stated in the error message, you can use `Tab.Container` & `Tab.Pane` to create your customs Tabs.

Reference to the [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-custom-layout):

> For more complex layouts the flexible TabContainer, TabContent, and
> TabPane components along with any style of Nav allow you to quickly
> piece together your own Tabs component with additional markup needed.

Example implementation of Tabs contruction with conditional rendering:

```
return (
  <Tab.Container defaultActiveKey={1}>
    <Nav variant="pills" className="flex-column">
      <Row>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey={1}>Tab 1</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey={2}>Tab 2</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        <Nav.Item>
          <Nav.Link eventKey={3}>Tab 2</Nav.Link>
        </Nav.Item>
        {this.state.type === type && (
          <>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link eventKey={4}>Tab 4</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link eventKey={5}>Tab 5</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
            <Nav.Item>
              <Nav.Link eventKey={6}>Tab 6</Nav.Link>
            </Nav.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Row>
    </Nav>

    <Tab.Content>
      <Tab.Pane eventKey={1} title="Tab 1">
        1
      </Tab.Pane>
      <Tab.Pane eventKey={2} title="Tab 2">
        2
      </Tab.Pane>
      <Tab.Pane eventKey={3} title="Tab 3">
        3
      </Tab.Pane>

      {this.state.type === type && (
        <>
          <Tab.Pane eventKey={4} title="Tab 4">
            4
          </Tab.Pane>
          <Tab.Pane eventKey={5} title="Tab 5">
            5
          </Tab.Pane>
          <Tab.Pane eventKey={6} title="Tab 6">
            6
          </Tab.Pane>
        </>
      )}
    </Tab.Content>
  </Tab.Container>
);
```

[image: Edit currying-dream-6xdqj]

In fact, if you view the components on React Dev Tools, you will notice that the "`Tab`" component in fact is not actually rendered when using `Tabs` & `Tab` combo - hence they defined it as "abstract" component

[image]

---

Alternatively, if you must use `Tabs` & `Tab` JSX combo, then you are going to have to implement the condition on the entire `Tabs` rendering - not just a section of it. You can find an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-pond-quc2b?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution by accident.

I used to declare component's name as `Tab` without import from `'react-bootstrap'` and using JSX condition rendering not any problem

But when I changed component's name to another, I found error from `'react-bootstrap'` and my JSX condition rendering didn't work anymore cause `'react-bootstrap'` wont accept JSX shorthand fragment or any.

So I declare empty component for handle error and using `<>...</>` in JSX condition rendering and everything works for me.

```
import React from "react";
import { Tabs } from "react-bootstrap";
    
const Tab = () => {
  return <></>; 
};
    
export const App = (props) => {
  return(
    <Tabs>
      <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1"><One/></Tab>                           
      <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2"><Two/></Tab>                           
      <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3"><Three/></Tab>   
      {props.type === type && (
        <>
          <Tab eventKey={4} title="Tab 4"><Four/></Tab>                           
          <Tab eventKey={5} title="Tab 5"><Five/></Tab>                           
          <Tab eventKey={6} title="Tab 6"><Six/></Tab>  
        </>
      )}
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

On top is not good practice but it's easy to declare condition.

In case you want to do with better practice use this instead.

```
import React from "react";
import { Tabs, Tab } from "react-bootstrap";
        
export const App = (props) => {
  return(
    <Tabs>
      <Tab eventKey={1} title="Tab 1"><One/></Tab>                           
      <Tab eventKey={2} title="Tab 2"><Two/></Tab>                           
      <Tab eventKey={3} title="Tab 3"><Three/></Tab>   
      {props.type === type && <Tab eventKey={4} title="Tab 4"><Four/></Tab>}
      {props.type === type && <Tab eventKey={5} title="Tab 5"><Five/></Tab>}
      {props.type === type && <Tab eventKey={6} title="Tab 6"><Six/></Tab>}
    </Tabs>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following official documentation. It is explained very well.
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Here is a sample code which I took from documentation. Hope this will clear your concept.

```
 render() {
const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
let button;
if (isLoggedIn) {
  button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
} else {
  button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
}

return (
  <div>
    <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
    {button}
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: No. this is related to only IF ELSE . That's I already used. This is about 'Tabs'